# Restricted Sort from Item Stack, Python

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, stack

I'm working on a Python problem that has me ordering items with some restrictions. The setup is this:

I have a stack of items given to me, and an order that the items should be in. The only way I am allowed to sort the items is to pull one item, and place it at the top of the pile. That is the only method allowed. I have to return the items I should pull, in order, to go from input --> suggested output in as few moves as possible.

As you can see in my code below, I thought the best way to do this would be simple: start at the bottom of the stack, and see if the items match where they should be. If they do, leave them and move to the next item pair (pair being input[i], output[i].) If not, pull the disc.

This doesn't seem to be the most efficient. See example below:

```
Sample Input Stack- top to bottom
EM, JPE, JB, RAA, CM

Expected New Stack- top to bottom
RAA, JPE, EM, CM, JB

Smallest Moves- order of pulled
CM, EM, JPE, RAA

What my code does- order of pulled
CM, RAA, JPE, EM, RAA, JPE, RAA
```

And here's my code that does the sort:

```
def takeInput(x):
infile = open(x, 'r')
num_blank = 0
first_stack = []
output_stack = []
stacks = []
for line in infile:
    if line.strip() == "":
        num_blank = 1
    else:
        if num_blank == 0:
            first_stack.append(line.strip())
            #add to start list
        else:
            #add to end list
            output_stack.append(line.strip())
stacks.append(first_stack)
stacks.append(output_stack)
return stacks

def pullDisc(currentStack, pos):
#this function takes a stack & position, pulls the item in that position and puts it on the top
temp = currentStack[pos]
currentStack.pop(pos)
currentStack.insert(0, temp)
return currentStack

def stackTest(startStack, endStack):
moves = []
for i in range(len(startStack)-1, 0, -1):
    while startStack[i] != endStack[i]:
        moves.append(startStack[i])
        pullDisc(startStack, i)
print(startStack, "from stackTest") #pull
return moves


x= input("Please enter the file name: ")
startStack = takeInput(x)[0]
endStack = takeInput(x)[1]
print(startStack, "starting") #pull
print(endStack, "ending goal") #pull
print(stackTest(startStack, endStack), "moves in order")
```

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: It was, in 2013 ;)

Comment: ;D I never read dates...